# Python Turtle Pong Game Ball and Paddle Collisions

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
#Paddle and Ball collisions

if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -40):
    ball.setx(340)
    ball.dx *= -1

if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -40):
    ball.setx(-340)
```

can anyone explain me about the first line of this code???Why -40 and +40 is used

Comment: A very similar question was asked a week ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63463330/2988 Unfortunately, the question has no answers, but everything is explained in the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am making a pong game in python using turtle ? Can anyone explain ball and paddle collisions part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463330/i-am-making-a-pong-game-in-python-using-turtle-can-anyone-explain-ball-and-pad)

Comment: I asked that question but i was not satisfied with the answer u just copied my old comment, please can u explain me only the ball and paddle collision part

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone explain me about the first line of this code???Why -40 and
> +40 is used

Both `ball.ycor()` and `paddle_b.ycor()` are points.  However, the paddle itself is some sort of rectangular entity 80 pixels tall.  So we need to determine if the point that is the ball's vertical center lies over any portion of the paddle:

```
and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -40)
```

A more idiomatic way to write this might be:

```
and paddle_b.ycor() -40 < ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40
```

[image]

Similarly for the ball's horizontal position:

```
(ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350)
```

or:

```
340 < ball.xcor() < 350
```

We don't need to consider the paddle's current horizontal position as it doesn't move horizontally -- it's in a fixed position with respect to the X axis.

Comment: Thank u very much Bro it helped me a lot. I think your explanation was the best